# what is the major difference libssh vs libssh2?

Tags: libssh2, libssh

I googled "libbssh vs libssh2" , couldn't find good explanation about the difference between of them.

What is the major difference ?

The main functionality that i need is copying files , which of the lib is recommended ?

Answer (score 5):

The difference mentioned in https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2-vs-libssh.html is nowadays almost outdated. There i believe was a time when libssh2 was more preferred but today libssh support new age cyphers like AES-GCM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Can you please point to a resource where we can explore more of recent developments in libssh ?

Comment: The best place to look for is the change log of libssh

Answer (score 2):

The differences are in the link [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103502/803378) by ericcuritin.

As you asked:

> The main functionality that i need is copying files, which of the lib is recommended?

I think SCP or SFTP might solve your problem, and yes, the two subsystems are both supported by `libssh` and `libssh2`.

However one of the main differences is that you can't implement server side applications with `libssh2`, so pick up `libssh` instead.

Comment: the [answered] link is broken, there is no answer by ericcuritin any more

Comment: @törzsmókus oh the link is https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2-vs-libssh.html

Answer (score -10):

libssh is based on SSH, which is considered obsolete.
libssh2 is based on SSH2 which is more secure and efficient than SSH and functionally similar to FTP, but SSH2 encrypted.

If you are concerned about security and performance, I recommend libssh2.

Comment: The support for SSHv1 has been removed since libssh-0.8.0, here's the [release note](https://www.libssh.org/2018/08/10/libssh-0-8-0/). That's to say libssh used to support both SSHv1 and SSHv2.